# c++ user defined member in copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
class A
{
std::string name;
public:
A(const A & rhs)
{
name = rhs.name;
}
};
```

In copy constructor of class A above, will the assignment operator of string class is called or copy constructor of string class?

name data member is not defined yet, so wouldn't the copy constructor be called?

Comment: Both, I think. First the copy constructor is called to make a copy of `rhs.name` that is the assigned with the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment operator.  If you want copy constructor:

```
A(const A& rhs)
: name(rhs.name)
{
}
```

Comment: name data member is not defined yet, so wouldn't the copy constructor be called?

Comment: @Medicine: no. Before you can enter the constructor's body, `name` has to be constructed in some way, so that you've got a complete object to work with. (If no constructor is specified as in this answer, C++ picks the default one.) From that point on, you can't just construct `name` _again_, you have to assign to it.

Comment: in this case, memory for A object is allocated and then if the copy constructor on A is called, it needs to initialize the name member. the memory for name is allocated but is not initialized before, so it will be defined for the first time in the constructor, so copy constructor of string class needs to be invoked.                       Isn't is similar to A a1; A a2 = a1; where a2 is copy constructed from a1 as a2 is defined for 1st time.

Answer (score 0):

A default (compiler-generated) assignment operator will be called that does a member-by-member assignment

Comment: name data member is not defined yet, so wouldn't the copy constructor be called?

Comment: @Medicine No.  The ctor for `name` has already been called by the time the body of A's ctor is entered.  If you want to use a ctor (copy or otherwise), you have to specify it outside of the body, like in Joe's answer.  Since `name` is already constructed, your example will invoke an assignment operator.